# Validação de Placa de Veículos Java

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces, validação

Alguém já sabe como fazer a validação das novas placas de veículos? [Placas de veículos devem começar a usar padrão do Mercosul daqui a 6 meses](https://g1.globo.com/carros/noticia/placas-de-carros-devem-comecar-a-usar-padrao-do-mercosul-daqui-a-6-meses.ghtml)

Em vez de 3 letras e 4 números, como é hoje, as novas placas terão 4 letras e 3 números, e poderão estar embaralhados, assim como na Europa.

1. A placa poderá ter no mínimo 2 caracteres iniciando com letras = MJ1234

   No entanto se for informado apenas 2 letras, o sistema só permitirá a inserção de 4 números, ainda que o total do campo seja de 7 caracteres.
2. A placa poderá ter 3 caracteres iniciando com letras = MJL1234

   Nesse caso permitirá digitação de até 4 caracteres em números, possibilitando digitação dos 7 caracteres.
3. A placa poderá ter 4 caracteres iniciando com letras = MJLC123

   Nesse caso também permitirá digitação dos 7 caracteres.

Além disso:

- O sistema não permitirá iniciar a digitação com números, deverá travar essa digitação.
- O sistema não permitirá digitação de outros caracteres que não sejam letras e números, exemplos: */+[%, e até mesmo espaço, deverá travar essa digitação.
- Após inserção de um número após as letras, o sistema não permitirá digitação de outra letra, exemplo: MJ12L8, deverá travar essa digitação.